# Can i make MMenu labels open up the submenu (not just the arrow)

Tags: mmenu

When I make a label in MMenu, it creates a arrow on the right " > " and only that arrow opens up the submenu. I'd like to make the entire label open up the submenu, and I'm wondering how I could do that. Below is a snippet of the first label and the code.

[image]

```
<li class="Label">
    <a href="socks/">Socks</a>
    <ul>
         <li><a href="1">1</a></li>
         <li><a href="2">2</a></li>
         <li><a href="3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, just change the

```
<a href="sock/">Socks</a>
```

to

```
<span>Socks</span>
```